# Progressbar while the splashscreen is loaded

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

what code does one enter for a progress bar on a splash screen? I basically want the splash to show while my application is launching, any links for documents are welcome, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Building an iPhone App for Tekpub - Splash Screen"](http://flux88.com/blog/building-an-iphone-app-for-tekpub-splash-screen/) tutorial, this should give you good working instructions.